# Servicestack MySql connection string

Tags: database-connection, servicestack

I'm trying to figure out how to create a connection string in Servicestack for (in this case) MySql.

The question is: what is the connection string in Web.config supposed to look like ?

I stumbled on two ways:

### **1)**

```
<appSettings>
<add key=   "ConnectionString" 
   value=   "Uid={User};
   Password={Password};
   Server=  {EndpointUrl};
   Port=    {EndpointPort};
   Database= customers" />
</appSettings>
```

---

and

### **2)**

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="testDb" 
    connectionString=
        "Server=   localhost;
         Database= test;
         UID=      root;
         Password= test" 
    providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

---

The question above is due to the fact that I have had a hard time to find an answer to this (apparently trivial) question. The answers I find are usually answering more complicated problems.

The Servicestack dokumentation looks like it's tuned to a rather more experienced audience than myself. Not by much but just, I'm a rookie at this.

This is a general problem I guess, in any documentation of a system. It's easy to go blind when it comes to fundamentals. What's self-evident to me is complicated for the next person.

Comment: If already deep into databases this is an example of self evident but not entirely 
obvious to a newbee:     
"Databases are called schema's in MySQL Workbench."
[Have a look in this blog](http://webvaultwiki.com.au/Default.aspx?Page=Create-Mysql-Database-User-Workbench&NS=&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Answer (score 2):

A connection string should contain your database connection in a single string, this is an example of a MySql connection string to the “test” database on “localhost”:

```
Server=localhost;Database=test;UID=root;Password=test;SslMode=none
```

You can use this as a template and replace it with the parameters with your database info.

You can add this in your web.config with:

```
<add key="ConnectionString" 
     value="Server=localhost;Database=test;UID=root;Password=test;SslMode=none" />
```

Which you can then access with ServiceStack's [AppSettings](http://docs.servicestack.net/appsettings) API:

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
    AppSettings.GetString("ConnectionString"), MySqlDialect.Provider));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mythz.  
One vital piece of information here is that the values of the connection string value is supposed to be put into one long string (separated by semicolons). I missed that.  
So in my question alternative 1) was the right one.  
My question was a little clumsy formulated, I meant to ask if alternative 1) or 2) was the right one, but you cleared that up.  
But where, when and how may alternative 2 be used ? (at the moment I don't recall where I saw that one).